# Async PartialView in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Does ASP.Net Core MVC have a native implementation of async PartialViews?
Because for now, I use sending ajax request to controller/action with some parameters, where partial view renders using received parameters by inside method, then converts to html string, which returns as ajax response. Then js script clears the necessary `<div>` element, and appends html string from ajax response.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC Core does have [async PartialViews](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-3.1#asynchronous-html-helper), but it has nothing to do with dynamic results requested by javascript later. If you want dynamic content without reloading the page, that is still going to require ajax.

Comment: @GSerg from your link this part:  @@await Html.PartialAsync("_PartialName")  bolong to razor view. But what the code must be on controller?  I can't see any PartialViewAsync(...)  methods on controller side.         

public async Task<IActionResult> GetTableBody()
 {
     var entities = await _repository.GetAsynd(); /// <--  async
     return PartialViewAsync(certificates);  /// <--- PartialViewAsync is not existed ?
 }

Comment: @nzim The controller methods do not return views, they return the description of what view should be rendered. So you don't have `PartialViewAsync`. Nor do you need one, because it's not going to make a difference at the point where you call `PartialAsync`.

Answer (score 0):

No, ASP.NET Core (Razor engine, to be exact) doesn't know how to render dinamically loaded partial views. It only knows how to render [ViewResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewresult?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for a way to render your partial view async, you can use

```
@Html.PartialAsync("_PartialName")
```

For more information you can check out this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Thanks, but maybe description of question a bit wrong. PartialView is already rendered in main view, and task is to refresh this partial view async, using new data, which is dynamically changes in main view.

Comment: oow oke. sorry. Now I understand your problem. Unfortunately I can not help you on that front. But the comment made by GSerg seems to be a good answer.

Comment: @GinoBlaazer Can you help to understand, what method should be on the asyn controller side? in pair to @Html.PartialAsync("_PartialName")